# Unable to extract most of the diameter AVPs using dpkt (python)

Tags: python, pcap

I need to extract all the `AVPs` details from the diameter packets. Currently I am using `dpkt lib` for `Python` but I figured out that it doesn't support extraction of all the AVPs.

At the header level, only followings are suppported

```
class Diameter(dpkt.Packet):
    __hdr__ = (
        ('v', 'B', 1),
        ('len', '3s', 0),
        ('flags', 'B', 0),
        ('cmd', '3s', 0),
        ('app_id', 'I', 0),
        ('hop_id', 'I', 0),
        ('end_id', 'I', 0)
        )
```

At the AVP level, are supported, rest of the AVPs are stored as binary data (if I am not wrong)

```
class AVP(dpkt.Packet):
    __hdr__ = (
        ('code', 'I', 0),
        ('flags', 'B', 0),
        ('len', '3s', 0),
        )

import dpkt

f = open('snoop.pcap','r')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)


for ts, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = eth.data
    tcp = ip.data
    dia = dpkt.diameter.Diameter(tcp.data)
    avp = dpkt.diameter.AVP(tcp.data)
    if tcp.dport == 3868 and len(tcp.data) > 0:
        print (str(dia.cmd) + ' ' + str(dia.hop_id) + ' ' + str(dia.end_id) + ' ' + str(avp.code))

f.close()
```

Are there any other lib better than dpkt or any other way to extract the AVPs using this lib?

Version: dpkt 1.8

Answer (score 0):

dpkt's Diameter parser has a bug (as of version 89).
According to RFC 3588, section 4:
"A number of zero-valued bytes are added to the end of the AVP Data field till a word boundary is reached.  The length of the padding is not reflected in the AVP Length field."

This padding is not implemented. Modify diameter.py like the following:
In the unpack() method of the AVP class (line 119), add:

```
self.padding = ( 4 - self.len % 4 ) % 4
```

In the __len__() method of the AVP class (line 140), add:

```
length += self.padding
```

These modifications solved the problem for me.